# Слитно или раздельно пишется "не параллельно"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, частица-не

Герметизация неподвижных разъемных соединений в таких системах бывает крайне затруднительной, т. к. уплотнительные поверхности фланцев расположены **непараллельно**, а при использовании уплотнения с неизменной толщиной оно чаще всего повреждается при монтаже вследствие неравномерного распределения усилия затяжки.

Comment: _Alenka: ...а при использовании уплотнения с неизменной толщиной оно чаще всего повреждается при монтаже **вследствие неравномерного распределения усилия затяжки**._ === Не-а... Уплотнение не из-за этого повреждается.

Comment: Ну это уже технический вопрос... Я в этом не разбираюсь настолько, чтобы спорить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: **расположены не параллельно (отрицание).**

В нацкорпусе **24 примера с раздельным написанием** (в прямом и переносном значении слова) и только один вариант со слитным написанием:

(1) Монтаж производится голым медным проводом d = l, 5 мм или 2 мм, как можно короче и **не параллельно** друг другу. [Н. Кораблев.1927]

....сюжеты эти развиваются **не параллельно**, не каждый сам по себе, но постоянно перекрещиваясь. [Семен Лунгин.  (1989-1996)]

(2)  Последние получаются из параллелоэдров путем их разделения на равные части, в общем случае ориентированные **непараллельно.** [Г. Б. Бокий, 1951]

**В словаре** отмечено только наречие "параллельно", но нет наречия "непараллельно". Да и прилагательное "непараллельный" имеет ограниченный круг значений (**область математики и переносный смысл**):

НЕПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНЫЙ, 1. Не являющийся параллельным (1 зн.). Боковые стороны трапеции непараллельны. 2. Разг. Несопоставимый, не аналогичный, несовпадающий.

Comment: Удивительно: перелопатить горы информации и сделать неправильный вывод. Интересно, где вы увидели отрицание? Главное, что отметили: "непараллельно" имеет ограниченный круг значений" (только не значений, а применения). Это применение как раз и входит в "ограниченный круг". Не разглядели?

Comment: Да, и этот пример я видела... в общем случае ориентированные непараллельно... Сибилла, спасибо Вам большое, значит здесь подразумеваемое отрицание...

Comment: @Alenka Знаете, я вообще удивлена, что в словаре дается слитное написание "непараллельный" для математики.  Дело в том, что параллельность или утверждается, или отрицается, но никакого конкретного смысла отрицание не имеет. А вот в переносном значении такой утвердительный смысл есть: непараллельный (разг.) - это неадекватный (в разных темах: слишком резкий, слишком  агрессивный и т.д.)

Comment: _Sibylla: В словаре отмечено только наречие "параллельно", но нет наречия "непараллельно"._ === Может, плохо искали? См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/51829/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Я пользуюсь словарями на Грамоте.ру   Для меня важно, что один из словарей толковый, причем в новой редакции, а другой академический орфографический. А вообще словарей много,  да только неизвестно, насколько им можно доверять.

Answer (score 1):

Слитное написание вполне возможно, здесь нет отрицания.

Comment: Все-таки в интернете я практически не нашла совпадений со словом _"непараллельно"_... И Гугл, и даже этот портал подчеркивают это слово как ошибку... так что мне кажется, слитное написание все же неверно...

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, "непараллельно" вполне имеет право на существование в технике, если  непараллельность является свойством объекта ("ориентированные непараллельно"), а не отклонением от предполагаемой/возможной параллельности ("сюжеты эти развиваются не параллельно"). В вашем примере без консультации с инженером трудно сказать, какой из случаев имеет место, скорее всего отрицание (трудности вызваны отсутствием параллельности). Мой совет: пишите раздельно.